# fetching single child row based on a max value using Django ORM

Tags: sql, django, inner-join, django-orm

I have a model, "Market" that has a one-to-many relation to another model, "Contract":

```
class Market(models.Model):
    name = ...
    ...

class Contract(models.Model):
    name= ...
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market, ...)
    current_price = ...
```

I'd like to fetch Market objects along with the contract with the maximum price of each. This is how I'd do it via raw SQL:

```
SELECT M.id as market_id, M.name as market_name, C.name as contract_name, C.price 
as price from pm_core_market M INNER JOIN
    (SELECT market_id, id, name, MAX(current_price) as price 
        FROM pm_core_contract GROUP BY market_id) AS C
ON M.id = C.market_id
```

Is there a way to implement this without using SQL? If there is, which one should be preferred in terms of performance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Django 1.1 (currently beta) adds [aggregation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) support to the database API. Your query can be done like this:

```
from django.db.models import Max, F

Contract.objects.annotate(max_price=Max('market__contract__current_price')).filter(current_price=F('max_price')).select_related()
```

This generates the following SQL query:

```
SELECT contract.id, contract.name, contract.market_id, contract.current_price, MAX(T3.current_price) AS max_price, market.id, market.name
FROM contract LEFT OUTER JOIN market ON (contract.market_id = market.id) LEFT OUTER JOIN contract T3 ON (market.id = T3.market_id)
GROUP BY contract.id, contract.name, contract.market_id, contract.current_price, market.id, market.name
HAVING contract.current_price =  MAX(T3.current_price)
```

The API uses an extra join instead of a subquery (like your query does). It is difficult to tell which query is faster, especially without knowing the database system. I suggest that you do some benchmarks and decide.

Comment: I would have assumed that the subquery is more efficient than two JOINs, but you're right that that shouldn't be assumed; benchmark it and see.

Comment: Ayman, thanks! As a Django newbie, it took me a while to get it working :) I have a question about the filter in the statement: There's a possibility for the -unlikely- event in which prices of more than one contract is equal. If so, the query will fetch them all, giving multiple contracts for a market, right?

Comment: @ozgur - Indeed, if two contracts have the same price (which also happens to be the maximum), both will be returned.

Comment: is there a remedy for that? due to the nature of the markets, when one is initialized, the prices of its contracts may easily be equal!

Comment: @ozgur - I think it's not possible to filter duplicates using a GROUP BY (as your query does) with the Django database API. However, You can iterate over the results and remove the duplicates yourself. Would this work for you?

Comment: @Ayman Thanks, I followed your advice and removed the duplicates. So sorry for this late message, I thought I had written one before.